# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php'

Tags: php, magento

This message show up when I'm trying to go into catalog/manage product:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php'
>   (include_path='/home/hoon/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php56/pear')
>   in
>   /home/hoon/public_html/includes/src/SSTech_Categorygridfilter_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid.php
>   on line 3

When I disable the compilation status everything is ok.

Kindly note that I used megeworks to import categories.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear and recompile magento's php-class.

You can run this line on terminal

```
php /magento-path/www/shell/compiler.php clear

php /magento-path/www/shell/compiler.php compile
```

or

You can run compilation process on magento admin menu. System > Tools > Compilation